# Получение нескольких запросов в Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Использую react-redux, redux-thunk. Есть сервер, есть запрос на него. Ответ приходит в виде {data:... , stop: false}. Необходимо, когда получаю stop: false делать запрос опять, но добавить к стейту ещё те данные, которые я получаю. Сама цепочка запросов должна кончаться, когда я получаю ошибку 500 или stop: true. Возник вопрос - как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю такой вариант подойдет, в редюсере еще нужно будет со старой инфо мержить новую.

```
...
   

        return (dispatch) => {
    function recursiveFunction() {
        axios(`/api/getInfo`).then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: "SOME_ACTION",
                user: res.data
            })
            if (res.data.stop !== true) {
                recursiveFunction()
            }
        })
    }

    recursiveFunction();
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло такое. Суть в том, чтобы передать массив в функцию, чтобы потом этот массив отправить в dispatch

```js
export default class SomeService {
    async getID() {
        const response = await fetch('https://some-service.com/getID')
        const data = await response.json()
        return data.searchId
    }

    async getInfo(id) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://some-service.com/someInfo?searchId=${id}`)
        if (response.status === 500) {
            return this.getInfo(id)
        }
        if (response.status === 404) {
            throw new Error('This is end of this line!')
        }
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    }
}


const getTicket = async (id, arr) => {
    const data = await someAPI.getInfo(id)
    const {array, stop} = data
    arr.push(...array)
    if (stop === false) {
        await getInfo(id, arr)
    }
}
```